# What is the difference between s, c and r commands in vi/vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to clarify this from the OReilly book on Vim, but the examples presented aren't clear enough.
Clarification via examples/use-cases instead of direct explanation would be very helpful.

The Sample text could be:

```
With a
screen editor,
you can
scroll the page, move the cursor.
```

Comment: How about trying them out for yourself in Vim?  I think that would be the best way to understand what they do.

Comment: I did. Though with all the suboptions they have, perceiving the difference isn't so easy for a beginner like me.

Comment: Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: Don't forget about o, O, R, S, C, and I in your reading. Also I find `tab help` much more enjoyable than `help` because it is full screen and allows me to chase down rabbit holes.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Assume you have `foo` in the document, and the cursor is on the `f`.

Now, pressing `rb` will change this to `boo`, and you are back in command mode. Pressing `sb` will accomplish the same, but you are in insert mode and can insert more characters. Finally, `c` requires some kind of motion; e.g. you can type `cw` to remove the whole word and enter insert mode. On the other hand, `cl` is essentially the same as `s`.

Comment: For me "cw" removes all characters from the cursor towards the end of the word. "ciw" would remove the whole word and put you into insert mode.

Comment: @Leonard Schuetz: `cw` doesn’t take you to insert mode? That’s surprising. `cw` and `ciw` by itself should behave mostly the same; `c3w` and `c3iw` don’t, though: For `iw`, spaces are counted as separate words. E.g., typing `c3w` when on the first character of `a b c d` will remove `a b c` (three words, not counting spaces), whereas `c3iw` in the same situation will remove `a b` (three “words”, the second one being the space). Both will then enter insert mode.

Comment: To understand better what will be deleted with `c`, you should use `v` instead. Example: `v3iw`. I also notice that there is a difference between `v3iw` and `vi3w`: `v3iw` == `v` + 3 x `iw`, while `vi3w` == `vi` + 3 x `w`. Both left and right sides of  the '==' are exactly the same. That's a good way to understand why the results are different.

Comment: is `ci` 'essentially the same' as `s` or is it actually the same?

Comment: There is also `Rb` that is similar to `sb` but instead of leaving you in insert mode, leaves you in replace mode.

Comment: To see the difference between `cw` and `ciw` move to the middle of a word and try it.

Answer (score 38):

### Descriptions

`s` (**s**ubstitute) will delete the current character and place the user in insert mode with the cursor between the two surrounding characters.  `3s`, for example, will delete the next three characters and place the user in insert mode.

`c` (**c**hange) takes a vi/vim motion (such as `w`, `j`, `b`, etc.).  It deletes the characters from the current cursor position up to the end of the movement.  Note that this means that `s` is equivalent to `cl`  (vim documentation itself claims these are synonyms).

`r` (**r**eplace) never enters insert mode at all.  Instead, it expects another character, which it will then use to replace the character currently under the cursor.

### Examples

Take your sample text, and image the cursor at the beginning of the word '`can`' (line 3).

Typing `spl<Esc>` in vi/vim.

Here, we have `s` for **s**ubstitute.  `pl` is the text to insert, and `<Esc>` will exit insert mode.  Put together, it will change `can` to `plan` like this:

```
With a
screen editor,
you plan
scroll the page, move the cursor.
```

---

Typing `cwcould<Esc>` in vi/vim.

`c` is for **c**hange, and `w` tells `c` to delete through the next word, `can`.  Next we type the text for insert mode, `could`.  Lastly, we need to type `<Esc>` again to exit insert mode.  The command will change `can` to `could` like this:

```
With a
screen editor,
you could
scroll the page, move the cursor.
```

---

Typing `rf` in vi/vim.

Here we type `r` for **r**eplace, then `f` as the new character which `r` uses to replace the original character with.  This changes `can` to `fan` like this:

```
With a
screen editor,
you fan
scroll the page, move the cursor.
```

---

### Notes

There's a lot of hidden uses to the simple commands in vi/vim that highlight more differences between these commands.  Since I almost always use vim over vi, these features might be vim-exclusive, I'm not certain.

Maximizing the utility of commands like `c`, `y`, and `d` that take motions requires having a good grasp of text-objects (type `help text-objects` in vim.  These aren't in vi.)

Because `r` takes a character instead of entering insert mode, you can input characters that would otherwise be difficult to add in.  Typing `r<C-R>` (that's `r`, then ctrl-`r`) replaces the current character with a ctrl-r character.  This might be surprising since pressing ctrl-r in insert mode awaits another key that is the register to paste.

All three of these commands can be repeated with the `.` command, substituting, changing, or replacing the same region relative to the cursor with the given text.

When typing a number `n` before the command, `s` and `c` delete `n` items (characters for `s`, or movements for `c`), and then inserts text once.  Using a number `n` before `r`, however, replaces the next `n` characters with that many copies of the chosen character.  For example, `4r0` could replace `1234` with `0000` all at once.

Answer (score 29):

```
:help c
:help s
:help r
```

Easy.

Instead of wasting your time on that book, learn how to use Vim's awesome internal documentation:

```
:h s
:h :command
:h 'option'
:h function()
:h ctrl-x
:h i_ctrl-x
:h subject
:h foo<Tab>
:helpgrep foo
```

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question asked.

Comment: I does not but it helps the learning process. which is the goal of asking this question in the first place.

Comment: Du coup c'est quoi la meilleure méthode d'apprendre vim?

Comment: @PatrickK. **Primo**, faire `$ vimtutor` autant de fois que nécessaire, histoire de bien comprendre les bases. **Secundo**, comme indiqué à la fin de vimtutor, passer au manuel de l'utilisateur, `:help user-manual`, qui est très facile à suivre et très concret et qui ne nécessite pas de connaissance préalables à part une familiarité raisonnable avec son système d'exploitation et un anglais de niveau lycée. **Tertio**, garder un œil critique sur ses usages, repérer des actions inefficaces, chercher des solutions, les appliquer… et ainsi de suite, pour toujours.

Comment: Merci :) des conseils simples et efficaces. J'ai l'impression qu'il y a des gros bouquins. Çe ne fait que décourager l'apprentissage je trouve ...

Comment: Entre les gros bouquins, les petits bouquins, les cours payants, les billets de blogs, les vidéos sur YouTube et les memes sur Twitter, ça peut effectivement être dur de s'y retrouver pour un débutant. C'est dommage, car toute cette industrie éloigne les petits nouveaux du manuel de l'utilisateur tout en ressassant son contenu.

Answer (score 2):

You may try these commands in visual block mode (press `<C-v>` to enter), they act a little different.

When you select a block of characters and then type `s`, it will immediately remove the block and enter insert mode, whatever you input next will be inserted in the same position on each of the lines affected by the visual block selection.

Command `c` basically does the same thing.

What interesting is command `r`, when you type `ra` after you select a block, it will replace every character in that block to `a` instead of just leave one column of `a`. I think this can be very useful at some point.